Curved div infinite scroll buble cover image animation
I want to create an animation where bubbles scroll infinitely from right to left in the background. The animation should have a curved path with space between the bubbles, similar to the example shown here:
I've tried several methods and managed to get the bubbles to scroll from right to left, but I haven't been able to achieve the curved path and proper spacing between the bubbles as shown in the image.
expected Output
import React from 'react';

const Footer = () => {
    const travelImages = [
        'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/26/67/42/266742e1a6565d6a94b6b881c441c2a3.jpg',
        // (other image URLs)
    ];

    // Function to generate random size for each avatar
    const getRandomSize = () => {
        const sizes = ['w-16 h-16', 'w-24 h-24', 'w-32 h-32']; // Tailwind sizes: small, medium, large
        return sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * sizes.length)];
    };

    return (
        <div className='w-full h-screen'>
            <div className='w-full h-[40vh] flex justify-center items-center bg-blue-300 overflow-hidden relative'>
                {/* Image wrapper moving from right to left */}
                <div
                    className='absolute flex space-x-4'
                    style={{
                        animation: 'moveLeft 30s linear infinite',
                    }}
                >
                    {travelImages.map((item, index) => (
                        <div
                            key={index}
                            className={`rounded-full overflow-hidden ${getRandomSize()} bg-gray-200`}
                        >
                            <img src={item} alt="travel" className='w-full h-full object-cover' />
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>

                {/* Inline Style Tag for Custom Animation */}
                <style>{`
                    @keyframes moveLeft {
                        0% {
                            transform: translateX(100vw); /* Start from the right side */
                        }
                        100% {
                            transform: translateX(-100vw); /* Move to the left side */
                        }
                    }
                `}</style>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Footer;


please add code using code-sandbox where I can see How it's currently looks like.

here you go @I_am_prince
link:- https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/myp7d5?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A57%2C15
Output i am looking for:- https://i.sstatic.net/EDjoMYoZ.png
